# Irrelevant java.io.NotSerializableException refering always to the same line of code

Tags: java, swing, serialization, drag-and-drop

Tonight I'm continuing to receive thousands of errors like this when I drag/drop an item that functioned very well in the morning. I have among 140 classes and I can't trace all the modifications I've done :(. But I have never changed anything related to the drag/drop functionality. I've been completely away from the line in the code where throws these exceptions. 
This is the part of my code that causes the exception:

```
Object obj = ts.getTransferable().getTransferData(TransferableProductJob.PRODUCTJOB_DATA_FLAVOR);
```

I have traced it from this line of the stackTrace:

```
at View.panels.WaitingListJPanel$JListTransferHandler.importData(WaitingListJPanel.java:209)
```

The complete stack trace is:

```
dic 10, 2013 12:21:45 AM View.panels.WaitingListJPanel$JListTransferHandler importData
SEVERE: null
java.io.NotSerializableException: View.panels.BarsJPanel$1
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:710)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at sun.awt.datatransfer.TransferableProxy.getTransferData(TransferableProxy.java:83)
    at java.awt.dnd.DropTargetContext$TransferableProxy.getTransferData(DropTargetContext.java:376)
    at View.panels.WaitingListJPanel$JListTransferHandler.importData(WaitingListJPanel.java:209)
    at javax.swing.TransferHandler$DropHandler.drop(TransferHandler.java:1536)
    at java.awt.dnd.DropTarget.drop(DropTarget.java:450)
    at javax.swing.TransferHandler$SwingDropTarget.drop(TransferHandler.java:1274)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer.processDropMessage(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:537)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer$EventDispatcher.dispatchDropEvent(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:851)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer$EventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:775)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetEvent.dispatch(SunDropTargetEvent.java:48)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4716)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processDropTargetEvent(Container.java:4566)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4417)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:723)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:693)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

My attemps:

- I made all the class references which were indicated by this
  exception transient or I made them a subclass of Serializable.(maybe
  it was done for more than 40 classes)
- Sometimes I hade an error
  saying not a valid class constructor and in this case I added a
  protected default constructor. So I continued to have the above
  exceptions for other classes.
- **New Attemp:** I tried to delete barJPanel and all relevant classes I see that the exception disapears but The DnD has stopped working. It's very sad because I haven't changed any code in the DnD part. I think it's fool when it creates new Objects using default constructors in some classes. my constructors are complicated and I wonder how Java wants manipulate the classes using only the default constructors.

By the way.

1. All the serializable classes in my app have their own
   SerialVersionUID
2. I never use anything related to serialization directly or indirectly in the whole app. So don't ask about my code. It's all JVM.

The main problem is that I can't continue my attemps because BarsJPanel is serializable because it is a subclass of JPanel and making it transient doesn't solve any problem.

---

Adding the anonymous class code: (GalvanicMachine is serializable)

```
    galvanicMachine.addProductJobsListener(new IProductJobsListener() {

        @Override
        public void productJobAdded(ProductJob pj) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    reconstructPanelMap();
                }
            });             
        }

        @Override
        public void productJobRemoved(ProductJob pj) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    reconstructPanelMap();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: `View.panels.BarsJPanel$1` is an _anonymous inner class_ of `View.panels.BarsJPanel`, ***not*** a subclass, that it wants to serialize but is not itself serializable.

Comment: I have only one anonymous class and it's a Listener! I don't think that it would be a good idea to make listeners serializable. Does swing serialize all its listeners. Why don't I receive any warning when I create an anonymous listener class as a listener?

Comment: If a reference to the anonymous instance is stored in a member of `BarsJPanel` then it would be subject to being serialized when `BarsJPanel` is serialized.  Mark that reference transient.

Comment: I did a new attempt and added the story. Btw, I added the code of the listeners.

Comment: So `GalvanicMachine` has a member collection that stores references to anonymous implementation instances of `IProductJobsListener`.  The collection where you store those references must be `transient`, or the implementation instances must be `Serializable`.

Comment: Thanks. You are right! That was the problem. But I still wonder why ActionListener of JButton isn't serializable. it belongs to JButton and JButton is Serializable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GalvanicMachine` has a member collection that stores references to anonymous implementation instances of `IProductJobsListener`. The collection where you store those references must be `transient`, or the implementation instances must be `Serializable`.

`ActionListener` is not an instance of (subclass of) `JButton`, it is *contained in* a `JButton`.  It would not make much sense to serialize an `ActionListener`.

Comment: But I hadn't told that ActionListener is an instance of JButton. I thing that AbstractButton has a list of ActionListeners the thing I exactly have here in this program bur for GalvanicMachine and IProductJobListener.